# wp query to use both author id and meta_query

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, meta-query, author

I'm trying to display posts of an author by id OR those posts which have a meta value as author ID.

I have a custom field in the posts section as Additional Author (`additional_author`) and now I want to query the posts accordingly.

Currently, I'm using these query args.

```php
$actual_posts_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'author' => 2,
);
```

And it displays the posts of author 2 perfectly.

But when I use `meta_query` with this one, it ignores it.

```php
$actual_posts_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'author' => 2,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'additional_author',
            'value'   => 2,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);
```

And if I use the remove author arg, it displays posts by `meta_query` perfectly.

Is there any way to display both of the posts?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the AND logic that wordpress uses when creating a sql query.

This query will look for posts that have both `author = 2` and meta query, additional_author that is LIKE 2.

Your best bet is to create your own query to achive this result.

I have created a static query for you to try

```php
global $wpdb;

$sql  = 'SELECT *';
$sql .= " FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p";
$sql .= " JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id";
$sql .= ' WHERE (p.post_author = 2';
$sql .= ' OR (pm.meta_key = \'additional_author\' AND pm.meta_value LIKE \'%2%\'))';
$sql .= ' AND p.post_type = \'post\'';
$sql .= ' AND p.post_status = \'publish\'';
$sql .= ' GROUP BY p.ID';
$sql .= ' ORDER BY p.post_date DESC';
$sql .= ' LIMIT 5';

$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

print_r($results);
```

This is almost an exact copy of the query WordPress has built but with a small change, `OR` instead of `AND`.

Its a bit resource pricy because OR logic will create two tables to search in but it will do the work.

We don't have to use `$wpdb->prepare` because all the sql is hardcoded by us, if you would like this query to be dynamic let me know and ill update the answer.

Comment: Any other way to do it without writing a custom DB query?

Comment: @RameezIqbal Not for the OR logic, at least not that I know of. But as I said this sql query is just a copy of the excat query that you have in `$actual_posts_args`, just switch one logic, from **AND** to **OR**